# R: how to keep only sd outliers in the dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset (`iris` for example) and I want to keep inside each column only the statistical outliers that are deviating for `mean` +/- 3.5*`sd` or more and transform all the other values into NA's.
What is the proper way of doing this in modern dplyr?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `between` with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
iris1 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ 
      case_when(between(., mean(.) - 3.5 * sd(.), mean(.) + 3.5 * sd(.)) ~ .)
            ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It doesn't work as intended because it gives as an output the exactly same dataset. Also what does `~ .` at the end mean?

Comment: @lim-lim It is based on the data ie. if there are no values that are outside those ranges, it will not change

Comment: Thank you, I was not fast enough to understand. As far as I wanted the inverse, the final answer for me looks like `iris1 <- iris %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ case_when(between(., mean(.) - 3.5 * sd(.), mean(.) + 3.5 * sd(.)) ~ as.numeric(NA), TRUE ~ . )))`

Comment: @lim-lim  In that case, you can just negate the whole expression i.e. `!(between(....)~`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is a great way of using `case_when`